# Shortcuts are not working in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

With every eclipse shortcut's are not working in my system.
FYI: I am using jdk1.6.0_33.
I tried with some of the eclipse version. 
I tried with deleting temp file etc.

Answer (score 0):

open you eclipse click "Windows"-->"preferences"-->"general"-->"keys" set for your ide. may it warks

Comment: Still no luck what is the exact problem I am not getting.

Comment: I am getting one dialog saying  ==>  The compilation unit is on the java build path of java project.

Comment: choose one command,and binding it (e.g in my ide,the "add javadoc coment" binding "alt+shift+j")